Removing laminate from countertops
If we remove laminate from our countertops down to the plywood or particle board what can we do with just that material? Ca. We seal that and paint it?

We need more details here.  What you can do and can't do is dependant on what material is under the laminate.  Also telling us why you desire removal may spawn other ideas to solve your problem.  Generally removal of laminate damages the surface it was on beyond repair.  Tells us your goal and we may be able to save you some time.

You can seal & paint it ... but it's not going to really be a functional kitchen countertop anymore unless you use a very hard/tough "paint" - probably an epoxy of some sort.

Just removing the laminate is not going to be fun, and most likely will leave a mess of a surface to fix.  Painting the laminate might be one idea.  Not as easy as drywall, but possible.

If your goal is a different look for your countertops. You have 2 choices.

Re-laminate over the old laminate.  Just glue the new over the old. A good router and a sharp file is about all you need. ( I know I've done it) However this works with square cut counters only. If your counter is "Post formed" with rounded edges and incorporated backsplash, this cannot be done.  Just replace the counter.  Removing the old laminate will damage the counter and you will need to replace it anyway.

Replace the counter.  Your options are:

Premade laminate counters.

Custom made laminate counters.

Butcher block counters.

Live edge plank

Epoxy covered wood

Stone, quartz, other solid surface counters.

Concrete counters

Tiled surface counters




Admittedly some of these are out of date; some costly, some may be impractical. However, we do not know your intentions so all the options have been presented. Removal of laminate and painting is outside the realm of realistically practical.
